# Excel VBA get data from webpage in enterprise network

Tags: html, excel, vba, web-scraping

I'am an entusiast with vba.
In my company we conect to internet throught a proxy .pac file.
I need to get the weather from accuweather.

With the help of what i read in web i managed to do something that works but outside the company, for example in my home.
This is the code that is called by a form where the user selects the city, month and year.

```
    Option Explicit

Sub GetExchangeRates(city As String, FromCurrency As String, Amount As String)

Dim XMLPage As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
Dim htmldoc As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim URL As String
Dim cn As String

Dim m As Long
Dim y As Date
Dim dfr As String

Dim d_until As Date
Dim MonthNm As String

MonthNm = FromCurrency
m = Application.Evaluate("=MONTH(1&" & Chr(34) & MonthNm & Chr(34) & ")")
y = Amount
dfr = Format(DateSerial(y, m, 1), "m/d/yyyy")

If city = "leiria" Then cn = "273891"
If city = "lisbon" Then cn = "274087"
If city = "porto" Then cn = "275317"
If city = "faro" Then cn = "273190"
If city = "coimbra" Then cn = "272818"

On Error GoTo Error_Handler

URL = "https://www.accuweather.com/pt/pt/" & city & "/" & cn & "/" & 
FromCurrency & "-weather/" & cn & "?monyr=" & dfr & "&view=table"

XMLPage.Open "GET", URL, False
XMLPage.send

htmldoc.body.innerHTML = XMLPage.responseText

ProcessHTMLPage htmldoc

Range("C1").Value = city
Range("D1").Value = Amount
Range("G2").Value = "Data"

Application.Run "FillRow"

Error_Handler_Exit:
On Error Resume Next
Exit Sub

Error_Handler:
MsgBox "Ocorreu um erro de rede." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
       "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
       "Error Source: getOperatingSystem" & vbCrLf & _
       "Error Description: " & Err.Description, _
       vbCritical, "Internet access error!"
Resume Error_Handler_Exit

End Sub

Private Sub OpenRatesForm()
RatesForm.Show

End Sub


Sub ProcessHTMLPage(HTMLPage As MSHTML.HTMLDocument)
Dim HTMLTable As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLTAbles As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
Dim HTMLRow As MSHTML.IHTMLElement
Dim HTMLCell As New MSHTML.HTMLDocument
Dim RowNum As Long, ColNum As Integer

Set HTMLTAbles = HTMLPage.getElementsByTagName("table")

For Each HTMLTable In HTMLTAbles
Debug.Print HTMLTable.className

Worksheets.Add
Range("A1").Value = HTMLTable.className
Range("B1").Value = Now

RowNum = 2
For Each HTMLRow In HTMLTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")
    'Debug.Print vbTab & HTMLRow.innerText

    ColNum = 1
    For Each HTMLCell In HTMLRow.Children
        Cells(RowNum, ColNum) = HTMLCell.innerText
        ColNum = ColNum + 1
    Next HTMLCell

 ''''   For Each HTMLCell In HTMLTable.getElementsByTagName("td")

 RowNum = RowNum + 1

 Next HTMLRow

Next HTMLTable

Set HTMLTAbles = Nothing
End Sub
```

If run this in company i get errors from access denied e others.
So I read more and find that doing this with ie could work.
It bypasses the issue with acessing to internet, but the issue is that i cant get do make to work with the form and sometimes the ie opens with the accuweather page but does not displays data in excel.

```
    Sub Grabaccuwther()

Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Dim ele As Object
Dim y As Integer
Dim url As String

'start a new browser instance
Set objIE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
'make browser visible
objIE.Visible = True

 url = "https://www.accuweather.com/en/pt/lisbon/274087/november-weather/274087?monyr=11/1/2018&view=table"

'navigate to page with needed data
objIE.navigate url

'wait for page to load
 Application.StatusBar = "Loading Web page …"
' wait until the page loads before doing anything

Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

'we will output data to excel, starting on row 1
y = 1

For Each ele In objIE.Document.getElementsByTagName("tr")

    'each 'tr' (table row) element contains 4 children ('td') elements
    'put text of 1st 'td' in col A
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & y).Value = ele.Children(0).textContent
    'put text of 2nd 'td' in col B
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & y).Value = ele.Children(1).textContent
    'put text of 3rd 'td' in col C
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & y).Value = ele.Children(2).textContent
    'put text of 4th 'td' in col D
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & y).Value = ele.Children(3).textContent
    'increment row counter by 1
    y = y + 1
Next

Application.StatusBar = "Web page Loaded!"
objIE.Quit

End Sub
```

I'm trying about a month do do this and I have changed some thinks but can't get this to work.
I aprreciate help to acomplish this.
Thanks.

Comment: Your problem statement is not specific enough.  Tell us the exact error you're getting, and on which line of code you are getting it.

Comment: Hi Robert, with the first code i have access denied in enterprise network but is because the .get line gives the error. The second works, only sometimes but with no errors.

Comment: OK, well the "Access Denied" error is an IT problem.  You're getting it because the folks running the enterprise network haven't given you those rights.

Comment: Thanks again Robert. That i know! and i managed to get the other code working, but the issue is that sometimes opens the ie page but dont pass data to sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is based on you saying IE can generally access the page (also ensure the site is whitelisted.)

Whole table:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetTable()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, hTable As HTMLTable
    Dim ws As Worksheet, t As Date
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.accuweather.com/en/pt/lisbon/274087/november-weather/274087?monyr=11/1/2018&view=table"
        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        With .document
            t = Timer
            Do
                DoEvents
                On Error Resume Next
                Set hTable = .querySelector(".calendar-list")

                On Error GoTo 0
                If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
            Loop While hTable Is Nothing

            If Not hTable Is Nothing Then
                Dim clipboard As Object
                Set clipboard = GetObject("New:{1C3B4210-F441-11CE-B9EA-00AA006B1A69}")
                clipboard.SetText hTable.outerHTML
                clipboard.PutInClipboard
                ws.Cells(1, 1).PasteSpecial
            End If
        End With
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Just the two columns you mention in comments:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GetTable()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer, hTable As HTMLTable
    Dim ws As Worksheet, t As Date, r As Long, c As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    Const MAX_WAIT_SEC As Long = 5
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://www.accuweather.com/en/pt/lisbon/274087/november-weather/274087?monyr=11/1/2018&view=table"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        With .document
            t = Timer
            Do
                DoEvents
                On Error Resume Next
                Set hTable = .querySelector(".calendar-list")

                On Error GoTo 0
                If Timer - t > MAX_WAIT_SEC Then Exit Do
            Loop While hTable Is Nothing

            If Not hTable Is Nothing Then
                For i = 1 To hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr").Length - 1
                    r = r + 1
                    ws.Cells(r, 1) = hTable.getElementsByTagName("th")(i).innerText
                    ws.Cells(r, 2) = hTable.getElementsByTagName("tr")(i).getElementsByTagName("td")(0).innerText
                Next
            End If
        End With
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

**References (VBE > Tools > References):**

1. Microsoft Internet Controls
2. Microsoft HTML Object Library